# Changing default language in WordPress on individual pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to translate pages in wordpress if the url contains the language `/fr/` in the url. I am testing on a local site where I would like the language to default to french when I create the page `http://localhost/fr/`.

I would like to do this for multiple languages - for example

```
`http://localhost/de/`.
`http://localhost/es/`.
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<?php echo language_attributes();?>

<head>
      <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <?php wp_head(); ?>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1><?php echo __('This is a Heading','basictheme')?></h1>
      <p>This is a new paragraph.</p>
      <?php wp_footer(); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php 


function basictheme_functions(){

    load_theme_textdomain('basictheme',get_template_directory().'/lang');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme','basictheme_functions')
?>
```

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: @Milap I would like to know how I translate the page if the url contains the parameter /fr/. The only way I can translate it at the moment is by changing the default language in WordPress(settings >> general >> site language) however i would like to change the language on individual pages.